# Wysimark on plain JS

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

There is [Wysimark](https://www.wysimark.com/docs/js) - WYSIWYG Markdown Editor. I need add it to page with plain JS, using `<script>` tag.

I installed it with `pnpm add @wysimark/standalone`

For some reason, it is not written in the [docs](https://www.wysimark.com/docs/js) how to add to page using the `script` tag, although it is written that the solution is `Plain JS` (or is it something else?)

I do it like this

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="editor-container"></div>
        <script defer type=module src='index.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`

```
import { createWysimark } from "@wysimark/standalone"

const container = document.getElementById("editor-container")

const wysimark = createWysimark(container, {
  initialMarkdown: "# Hello World",
})
```

An error appears

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/cmwysiwig/node_modules/@wysimark/standalone/.dist/browser/index.cjs.js' does not provide an export named 'createWysimark' (at index.js:1:10)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The docs doesn't say anything about it, but I assume that it expects you to use a module bundler, like Webpack, to compile your script.

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup (bundler?). It should load *@wysimark/standalone/.dist/browser/index.esm.js* not *@wysimark/standalone/.dist/browser/index.cjs.js*.

Comment: Thank you, but docs doesn't anything about `bundler`(

I don't know how to setup and run it( So it's not `PlainJS` it's `BundlerJS` (

Comment: @FreeStyler No, you already are doing some bundling, perhaps without noticing it. Otherwise `import { createWysimark } from "@wysimark/standalone"` wouldn't work in a browser, that's not a valid URL. As you can see from the error message, some of your tooling has already rewritten the path to `'/cmwysiwig/node_modules/@wysimark/standalone/.dist/browser/index.cjs.js'`, and that was the wrong one.

Comment: No, unfortunately there no one bundler( Just some HTML in PHP and plain JS... I assume that developer of Wysimark make some build that dosen't work https://imgur.com/fuHjuh3 . I will most likely have to contact the developer( Thank you for clarification

Comment: @FreeStyler Uh, the code in that image is not the same as the code in your question? As the error message you posted doesn't match the code you posted, I had to assume there was a build step you didn't tell us about.

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, you should import `…/index.esm.js` not `…/index.cjs.js`.

Comment: `index.esm.js` gets error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: Hm that is really weird, one would have expect the "standalone" version not to `import "react"` but as you can see from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wysimark/standalone?activeTab=code, it actually does…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by the package not exposing the `createWysimark` function in the CommonJS (CJS) build and the ESM build not inlining/bundling the imports. You can solve this by using a bundler to re-bundle/package the code like so:

```js
import { buildForBrowser } from '@jsheaven/easybuild'

await buildForBrowser({
  entryPoint: '$theWysimarkStandaloneDistFile.js', // still having import statements
  outfile: './dist/javascript/index.js', // imports are resolved/bundled in now; this file can be used directly via <script> inject; but still needs to be shipped via a CDN or webserver
  dts: false,
  debug: process.argv.indexOf('--dev') > -1,
  esBuildOptions: {
    logLevel: 'error',
  },
})
```

So for now, as the author has several issues open on his repo regarding [this](https://github.com/portive/wysimark/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+plain+JS), there is a quick fix using the `wysimark-standalone` npm package, which does exactly that. You can load the resulting bundled code via unpkg directly:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.unpkg.com/wysimark-standalone/dist/javascript/index.cjs.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor-container"></div>
    <script>
      const container = document.getElementById("editor-container")
      // createWysimark is available on window now
      const wysimark = createWysimark(container, {
        initialMarkdown: "# Hello World",
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a Codesandbox to demo it: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wysimark-standalone-ljlkh3?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00063b6mbhmbkfzx%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00023b6mtkf872vw%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00033b6m96o3uic8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00053b6mcnsayf00%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu8fzh3r00023b6mtkf872vw%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3q00013b6mz5ku4jvi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00023b6mtkf872vw%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3q00013b6mz5ku4jvi%2522%257D%252C%2522clu8fzh3r00053b6mcnsayf00%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00043b6mkx18cf17%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00053b6mcnsayf00%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00043b6mkx18cf17%2522%257D%252C%2522clu8fzh3r00033b6m96o3uic8%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu8fzh3r00033b6m96o3uic8%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)